# Java equivalent to MSDN API reference (local application)?

Tags: java, api, reference

I have a copy of the Java documentation. It takes me forever to find what I'm looking for, I can't search, and the layout is terrible.

Is there an MSDN equivalent to an API reference for Java, that will run in an application that provides a searchable index and categories?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, if you're are using windows or a chm viewer on linux or something else, at this site: http://www.allimant.org/javadoc/index.php
you can find the complete api reference in an unique file (indexing and searching capabilities are also available)

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I was looking for. THANKS! I can't believe Oracle doesn't link to something like this at least.

Comment: Glad to help!!, Sun did link to it, but it seems that with the move Oracle totally forgot about it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use NetBeans, you can do a full text search in the Javacocs API (Shift-F1), right from within the editor (e.g. the selected word)